My Zustand state doesn't change in an async function call but can change on a button click
I have an alert dialog that I want to call every time my Zustand state changes via a function call.
In a button onclick, it can change the state and open the alert dialog. But in an async function call, the state doesn't change when that Zustand state change function is called.
Is there something I'm missing regarding async functions and client components vs server components?
My alert dialog I want to open
// src/components/geofencing-alert.tsx
"use client";


import React from "react";
import {
    AlertDialog,
    AlertDialogAction,
    AlertDialogCancel,
    AlertDialogContent,
    AlertDialogDescription,
    AlertDialogFooter,
    AlertDialogHeader,
    AlertDialogTitle,
    AlertDialogTrigger,
} from "../ui/alert-dialog";
import { useAlertStore } from '../../store/useAlertStore';

const GeofencingAlert = () => {
    const { isAlertOpen, closeAlert } = useAlertStore();

    return (
        <AlertDialog open={isAlertOpen} onOpenChange={closeAlert}>
            <AlertDialogTrigger>Open</AlertDialogTrigger>
            <AlertDialogContent>
                <AlertDialogHeader>
                    <AlertDialogTitle>Warning: Tray is out of bounds</AlertDialogTitle>
                    <AlertDialogDescription>
                        A tray is currently out of bounds. Please check the antennas at each doors.
                    </AlertDialogDescription>
                </AlertDialogHeader>
                <AlertDialogFooter>
                    <AlertDialogAction>Continue</AlertDialogAction>
                </AlertDialogFooter>
            </AlertDialogContent>
        </AlertDialog>
    );
};

export default GeofencingAlert;


This is my Zustand alert store
// src/store/useAlertStore.ts

import { create } from 'zustand'

interface AlertState {
    isAlertOpen: boolean;
    openAlert: () => void;
    closeAlert: () => void;
}

export const useAlertStore = create<AlertState>((set) => ({
    isAlertOpen: false,
    openAlert: () => set({ isAlertOpen: true }),
    closeAlert: () => set({ isAlertOpen: false }),
}));



this is my nav. There is a button with onclick of openAlert
"use client"

import Link from "next/link";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";
import { docsConfig } from "@/config/docs";
import { siteConfig } from "@/config/site";
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";
import { Icons } from "@/components/nav/icons";
import { useAlertStore } from '../../store/useAlertStore';


export function MainNav() {
    const pathname = usePathname();
    const { isAlertOpen, openAlert, closeAlert } = useAlertStore();

    return (
        <div className="mr-4 hidden md:flex">
            <Link href="/" className="mr-6 flex items-center space-x-2">
                <Icons.logo className="h-6 w-6" />
                <span className="hidden font-bold sm:inline-block">
                    {siteConfig.name}
                </span>
            </Link>
            <nav className="flex items-center gap-4 text-sm lg:gap-6">
                {docsConfig.mainNav?.map((item) =>
                    item.href ? (
                        <Link
                            key={item.href}
                            href={item.href}
                            className={cn(
                                "transition-colors hover:text-foreground/80",
                                pathname === item.href || pathname.split("/")?.[1] === item.parentLink ? "text-foreground" : "text-foreground/60"
                            )}
                        >
                            {item.title}
                        </Link>
                    ) : null
                )}
                <button onClick={openAlert}>Test Alert</button>

            </nav>
        </div>
    );
}


this is my aysnc function. i called openAlert() but it doesnt open
//src/domain/geofenceControl.ts

import { Function } from '@prisma/client';
import { TagReportingData } from '@/types/ura8';
import { getReadersWithGeofenceAntennas as getReadersWithGeofenceAntenna } from '@/data/local/readerRepo';
import { useAlertStore } from '@/store/useAlertStore';

/**
 * Monitors geofence antennas for new data and logs when trays move out of bounds.
 */
export async function monitorGeofenceAntennas(data: TagReportingData[]) {
    const reader = await getReadersWithGeofenceAntenna()
    const { openAlert } = useAlertStore.getState();

    if (!reader) {
        console.log('No readers with geofence antennas found.');
        return;
    }

    const geofenceAntennas = reader.antennas.filter(antenna => antenna.function === Function.GEOFENCE);

    // Check if the tag has been detected by a geofence antenna
    const geofenceTags = data.filter(tag => geofenceAntennas.some(antenna => antenna.antennaPort === tag.antennaPort));
    const epcsDetectedByGeofence = geofenceTags.map(tag => tag.epcHex);
    // console.log("[geofencecontrols-tsx]: ", epcsDetectedByGeofence.length)
    if (epcsDetectedByGeofence.length === 0) {
        console.log(`No trays detected by geofence antennas on reader ${reader.id}.`);
        return;
    }

    console.log(`Trays detected by geofence antennas on reader ${reader.id}:`);
    openAlert(); //<---- alert called, but doesnt open
    epcsDetectedByGeofence.forEach(epc => {
        console.log(`  EPC: ${epc}`);

        // UPDATE TRAY TABLE HERE!!!!!!
    });
}


